# How to create DBContext/Tenant Factory per user in Dot Net Core 2.2, JWT

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-2.2

I have two DBContext in my web API app. 1st one is to have all my clients with their connestionstring and 2nd one is real app DB.

Login controler use MyClientContext & other all controllers use MyContext

My `startup.cs` looks

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)

            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
                    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext")));

        services.AddDbContext<MyClientContext>(options =>
                    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyClientContext")));
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate(); // Code First Migrations for App DB

        var context2 = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyClientContext>();
                context2.Database.Migrate(); // Code First Migrations for Clients DB
            }

            app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

On Login success, I issue JWT Token that looks

```
private string GenerateJSONWebToken(UserAuth userInfo)
        {
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userInfo.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, userInfo.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"], _config["Jwt:Issuer"], claims,
              expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), signingCredentials: credentials);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
```

Here, I have assigned ConnectionString for real DB at startup file. I want to assign this, when user logs in. How do I achieve this?

Comment: First of all, your question should have a question mark, as this is a Question and Answer Website. Secondly, "How do I resolve this", resolve what? You haven't described a problem

Comment: @MindSwipe, I updated my question.

Comment: Why should every user get his/ her own DBContext?

Comment: @MindSwipe, We have a situation that my app clients will use their individual database with same common db schema but web app is one only.So we want to change connection string to his/ her respective individual database.

Comment: But why create potentially hundreds if not thousands of databases for hundreds r thousands of clients? This seems like a really bad practice

Comment: It has its own pros & cons, we wanted to go like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187104/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-ramesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done below changes in my code and its working as expected now. It may useful to some one else.

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
            {
                var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
                var connection = GetConnection(httpContext);
                options.UseNpgsql(connection);
            });

private string GetConnection(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var UserName = httpContext?.User?.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti)?.Value;
             // Here extract ConnectionString from "MyClientContext"'s DB
        }
```

And for Code First DB Migration, I moved `Database.Migrate()` to its Class

```
public MyContext (DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.Migrate();
        }
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: You are a time saver!